# How to integrate a HTML page with the Tikiwiki

Tags: html, tiki-wiki

I have a standalone HTML page. I want to put this as another page/link on Tikiwiki.
Both the server and Page are on my machine only.

Comment: Integrate what? How? Where? Where is the Wiki running? What do you mean by integrate exactly, Tikiwiki showing up in an HTML page or the other way around? Are they both on the same server? What kind of an HTML page is it, a full page or just the body part? Add a little more detail.

Comment: Please check the updated one.

Answer (score 1):

If activated, you can use HTML in wiki pages. So you basically just put the code in the wiki page and check "Use HTML"

You can also use http://doc.tiki.org/PluginHTML which has the benefit that people with enough permissions must approve the use of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the IFRAME pluging to include the external HTML page within the wiki page.